# Pass value to a private property

Tags: ios, swift

I have a couple of private properties defined like so..

```
private var tableConfig : TableViewConfig<Company, CompanyCell>?

private var tabledata = [Company]() {
    didSet {
      tableConfig?.items = tabledata
    }
  }
```

Now there are 2 other properties defined like so...

```
  var model: Model?
  var companyCell: TableviewCell?
```

Now, if get the value in model as `Industry` and the value in companyCell as `IndustryCell`, how can I update these values to `private var tableConfig : TableViewConfig....` and `private var tabledata = [Company]()....` so that they will ultimately have the values like so..

```
private var tableConfig : TableViewConfig<Industry, IndustryCell>?

private var tabledata = [Industry]() {
    didSet {
      tableConfig?.items = tabledata
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `get` `set` variabile to achieve this result

```
var _tabledata: [Industry] {
        get {
            return tabledata
        }
        set {
            tabledata = newValue
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the attribute `private` implies properties and functions declared as `private` can only be accessed within the scope they are declared.

You have two options:

1. Change the access control to `fileprivate` (if the caller is in the same file) or `internal` or lower restriction.
2. Add an `internal` or lower restriction computed property or method in the scope of the private property to set it.

Answer (score 0):

You can expose an `init()` or a `method` to set the value of `private properties`, i.e.

```
class SampleClass {
    private var tableConfig : TableViewConfig<Company, CompanyCell>?
    private var tabledata = [Company]() {
        didSet {
            tableConfig?.items = tabledata
        }
    }

    init(tableData: [Company]) {
        self.tabledata = tabledata
    }

    func add(item: Company) {
        self.tabledata.append(item)
    }
}
```

You can create an `init` in case you want to `initialise` your `private variable` and use a `method` in case you want to `update` the `private variables`.

Comment: Ok @PGDev..but I have 2 concerns..hope you won't mind...1.how can I update the `tableviewConfig` and  2. Where and how do I add the updated values so that they are finally reflected..?

Comment: For that you need to add the definition of `TableViewConfig`. Also, you can update the `tableviewConfig` in the same way. I didn't understand your 2nd question.